# Is it possible to create a chatter group with only read/write access to group admin and rest of users to have read access to the group?

Tags: chatter, profile, user, permission-sets

Can we create a Chatter group where no one could post in, other than the admin?  So for example, I could post the training videos there, but no one could post in the group

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create **Broadcast Only group**

> Only group owners and managers can create new posts. Group members can comment on the posts.

[image: broadcast only]

Comment: Cool thank you. I will try it out and will let you know if this works for us.

Comment: Hi Santanu, Actually I have another question.  Instead of Private group, can there be a public group with the same abilities as I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, possible. Private group is for customers

Comment: Cool. Thank you

Comment: If my answer serves your purpose then accept this, so that others may find this useful